# AcquireCredentialsHandle returns massive expiration time

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

I'm working on a .Net wrapper for the [Windows SSPI API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#sspi_functions). Several API functions return expiration times, eg, for credential or security context expirations.

The expiration is stored in a 64-bit structure, [TimeStamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380511%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which stores the number of 100-nanosecond ticks since Jan 1, 1601 00:00 UTC.

When I invoke [AcquireCredentialsHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374712%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the raw value of the `TimeStamp` that is returned is massive - typically a value such as `0x7fffff154e84ffff`, eg, `HighPart = 0x7fffff15` and `LowPart = 0x4e84ffff`. When converted to a real time, this value is somewhere in the year 30848.

Does anybody know why the value is so unbelievably high?

It looks suspicious since it's quite near to overflowing a signed integer. I checked the docs to see if the value is used to store anything like flags or some other structured data, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Other parts of the API sometimes return similar values, and sometimes return values that indicate 5 minutes into the future.

I should mention that I'm using this API with the Negotiate package, which likely turns into the NTLM package since my workstation is not part of a domain.

Comment: You are in NY, currently at UTC-4:00.  Exactly by which the value is off from the maximum possible value.  You simply got a "never expires" value, adjusted by your timezone offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are in NY, currently at UTC-4:00. Exactly by which the value is off from the maximum possible value. You simply got a "never expires" value, adjusted by your timezone offset. –  Hans Passant

Comment: How does this make a sense because the lifetime of a Kerberos ticket, e.g., is 10 h in Windows.

Comment: @Michael-O SSPI supports more than just Kerberos. From my original question: "I should mention that I'm using this API with the Negotiate package, which likely turns into the NTLM package since my workstation is not part of a domain."

Comment: The you should try Digest SSP, it gives me: Status: 0
CredHandle: 4256/2397400
Year: 1632-03-21T02:24:34Z